# new Date in the context of a string doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, node.js, google-chrome

The last log in the following code doesn't work in Firefox. Why?

```
(function() {

    String.prototype.toDate = function() {
        return new Date(this);
    };

    console.log(Date.parse("2012-01-31"));
    console.log(new Date("2012-01-31"));
    console.log("2012-01-31".toDate());

})();
```

To test this in a browser, I put the snippet above into a file and used the following HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    <script src="wtf.js"></script>
</body>
```

NodeJS (v0.4.12):

```
1327932000000
Mon, 30 Jan 2012 14:00:00 GMT 
Mon, 30 Jan 2012 14:00:00 GMT
```

Chrome (17.0.963.79):

```
1327968000000
Tue Jan 31 2012 10:00:00 GMT+1000 (EST)
Tue Jan 31 2012 10:00:00 GMT+1000 (EST)
```

Firefox (10.0):

```
1327968000000
Date {Tue Jan 31 2012 10:00:00 GMT+1000 (EST)}
Date {Invalid Date}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` in Firefox's String.prototype appears to not reference the string, as a string. If you add to your method:

```
String.prototype.toDate = function() {
        return new Date(String(this));
    };
```

it works alright.

Comment: Interesting. `new String(this)` doesn't work but `String(this)` and `this.toString()` works.

Comment: You should also be able to use `('2012-01-31').toDate()` but I can't test it right now.